# Sensitivity analysis and data tables

Tags: excel

I want to perform a four way sensitivity analysis using data tables in Excel.

My problem is the following. I have four variables, let's call them A, B, C and D. A and B are continuous variables and can take values from 0 to 10. C and D are discrete: A can take only 5 distinct values and C can take only 2 distinct values.

For each pair of C and D (totally 5*2=10 pairs) we can build a data table with A as columns and B as rows. For each data table, I will calculate the mean value of all entries. So, I will have 10 values, one for each pair of C and D. I want to put these 10 values in a data table with C as column and D as rows.

The design I thought of is to create a data table for variables A and B, lets say in cells A1:H10, and below calculate the average of all entries of this data table, lets say at cell B12. Then, I have another data table for variables C and D, lets say at  cells C15:D19, that uses B12 as an input. My problem is that the second data table is not working, only giving the same output for all cells, the average at B12 for the first pair of C and D. for the rest of the pairs of C and D, there are no different values.

Could you please propose a way that I can do it work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A VBA solution would be to loop through the 10 possibilities for C,D and for each of them recalculate the table and then record the result.

Without VBA, a brute-force approach would be to have 10 separate tables (which ideally could be created once and then copied 9 times in such a way that the each copy automatically uses the correct values of C,D). Alternatively, you can use some of the tools under `Data/What if analysis`. See [this](http://www.sumwise.com/blog/sensitivity-analysis-spreadsheets/) for an excellent discussion of using these tools for sensitivity analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have done it using VBA, I forgot to write it. I would like to do it without using VBA. I will take a look at the discussion you suggested, thanks.